# Looking for alternatives for this sentence!

Tags: sentence

I am looking to replace a line in a video script.  Current line is:  "Have you ever been in a situation where..."  I am looking for a different way to convey that same concept to differentiate our 2nd edition of the video from the 1st edition.  Thanks!

Comment: Just eliminate "been in a situation where".

Comment: The "...been in a situation where... " is almost certainly excess baggage.  Try writing the sentence without the "concept."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**Does this (situation) sound familiar (to you)?**" or "**Have you (ever) experienced this?**" would be common ways to express the same inquisitive idea.